# Is there an sqlca.sqlcode or similar for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, powerbuilder

Coming from Powerbuilder and moving into PHP/MySQL. We often use SQLCA.SQLCODE to check if our SQL statements have been successful. Is there something similar for MySQL?

```
IF SQLCA.SQLCODE = 0 THEN
  // do something
ELSE
  // do something else
ENDIF
```

As far as I can tell [mysqli_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) seems to be the most similar though I'm not sure if it's what we're looking for.

If not, could someone point me out as to how this could/should/would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to use errno. Checking [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/mysqli_query) result is sufficient:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
> other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

so (mind the [comparision operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)!)

```
if( mysqli_query("....") !== false ) {
    // ok
} else {
    // zonk
}
```